# what will be the value of the following definite integral?

Tags: calculus

how do we find the value of the following definite integral?

$$I=\int_{-1}^{\infty}\cos(\pi t)dt$$

$-1 \le \cos(\pi t) \le 1$

$$I=\left[\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi}\right]_{-1}^{\infty}$$

Answer (score 2):

If the upper limit of an integral is $\infty$ (along with some other cases), it is an [improper integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral).  In this case it should be considered to be $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\int_{-1}^x \cos(\pi t)\; dt=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {\sin \pi x}\pi - \frac {\sin (-\pi)}\pi$$ which does not converge

Comment: it does not diverge either. does it ?

Comment: @RajeshKSingh:  It does not go off to infinity, but oscillation is another form of divergence.

Answer (score 1):

This diverges. There is no definite integral.  Recall that $I = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi} - \frac{\sin(-\pi)}{\pi}$

Its obvious that the sine does not converge. It oscillates forever.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that the sine function does not converge we can use the sequential characterization of limit so  we take for example the sequence $(u_n)_n=\left((2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)_n$ that diverges to $+\infty$ and $\sin u_n=(-1)^n$ also diverge.